# How to use QStackedWidget/QStackedLayout in PyQT/PyKDE?

Tags: pyqt, pykde

I am trying to create a properties panel as part of a larger application, which uses PyKDE and PyQT. QStackedWidget and QStackedLayout look right, but the situation is a bit complicated:

- The QStacked(Widget|Layout) is a subitem of a splitter,
- The QStacked(Widget|Layout) contains:

  - A text field
  - A QFormLayout (for the properties)

Using a QStackedWidget means I can't add layouts (only widgets), using QStackedLayout results in all sorts of problems, because everything expects to work with widgets rather than layouts.

How can I get out of this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could add QFrames to your stacked widget and then adding the necessary widgets to the frame